# Typescript function does not end after the first return?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that basically searches a list to see if there is a match to my target item. I have the following code:

```
var subjectTimePoints = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var selectedTimePoint = 9;
function subjectIdRequiredTimepoint() {
        this.subjectTimePoints.forEach(timepoint => {
            if (timepoint === this.selectedTimePoint) {
                console.log('TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT');
                return true;
            }
        });
        console.log('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF');
        return false;
}

subjectIdRequiredTimepoint();
```

The function will still print out 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' and return false even though I it printed out 'TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT' first. So why doesn't the function end after the first return?

Comment: The first return does not return from `subjectIdRequiredTimepoint`.It only returns from the function passed to `forEach`.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: You can't break in `forEach`. I guess you can use `Array.prototype.some()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `return` inside your `forEach` does not return the control from `subjectIdRequiredTimepoint`. It only returns from the callback function to `forEach`.

Your logic can be easily replaced like below using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control):

```
function subjectIdRequiredTimepoint() {
    let isMatched = this.subjectTimePoints.some(timepoint => timepoint === this.selectedTimePoint);
    if (isMatched) {
        console.log('TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT');
    }
    else {
        console.log('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF');
    }
    return isMatched;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!